# how to refresh a page in php using php background process? Is there ajax backround Process?

Tags: php, process, background

How to refresh a page every 10 minutes using php background process?
When i login to my account i can check my messages ,on setting timeout function the page reloads every 10 minutes but i need the process to run in background ,
After me logging in,.. if i receive some message i must receive a popup called hai you have a message from this sender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing i understood due to multiple reasons was the refresh every 10  minutes.  You can't use php, you must use javascript like so:

```
<body onload="setInterval('window.location.reload()', 600000);">
```

Comment: If the page reloads while filling a form then i would be messy

Comment: @udaya :Yes, that will happen no matter how you choose to reload though.

Answer (score 0):

You could send a header to the client side with PHP

```
header("refresh:600"); //600 seconds = 10 minutes
```